# About the Customer Annotation Processor, Why the size of set return by getElementsAnnotatedWith() is 0

Tags: java, java-8, annotations

I'm learning about Annotation in Java. I have found two problem I don't know why.

These are my test codes:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface MyTag {}
```

---

```
@MyTag
public class MyClass {
    @MyTag
    int id;
}
```

---

```
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({ "MyTag" })
public class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override

    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        PrintWriter pw1 = null;
        PrintWriter pw2 = null;
        PrintWriter pw3 = null;

         try {
         pw1 = new PrintWriter(new File("temp1.txt"));
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
         pw1.println("pw1 can work here");

         //why here print 0, the set is not empty
         pw1.println(roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyTag.class).size());

        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyTag.class)) {
            pw1.println("pw1 can't work here");

             try {
             pw2 = new PrintWriter(new File("temp2.txt"));
             } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             }

             pw2.println("pw2 can work here");

             //why here print 0, the set is not empty
             pw2.println(element.getEnclosedElements().size());

            for (Element ele : element.getEnclosedElements()) {
                pw2.println("pw2 can't work here");

                try {
                    pw3 = new PrintWriter(new File("temp3.txt"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                pw3.println("only pw3 can work");
                pw3.println(ele.getSimpleName());

                pw3.close();
            }
            pw2.close();
        }

        pw1.close();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have create PrintWriter in different block.

But like I have noted in the code above, some of them didn't work in specific block.

I wonder know why?
When we iterate a normal set, the PrintWriter should work I think.

Also, I found that the size of set I get from the method is 0.

But indeed these sets can be iterated, so I can't understand why.

Thank you for reading my question.

---

More details for my test

the files I have gotten are like this:

temp1.txt

```
pw1 can work here
0
```

temp2.txt

```
pw2 can work here
0
```

temp3.txt

```
only pw3 can work
id
```

Comment: A set returning size 0 when it contains elements sounds very strange and should not happen. My guess is that you are either running an old versions of your code or that you are seeing output from a previous run. If everything is correct then I would go through the application with a debugger

Comment: @kapex Thank you for answering my question, my jdk version is 1.8.0_181. I put MyClass.java, MyProcessor.class, MyTag.class in one folder. And use cmd to compile MyClass.java. So I got MyClass.class, temp1.txt, temp2.txt, temp.txt well. In temp1.txt there is word: "pw1 can work here" and "0". In temp2.txt there is word: "pw2 can work here" and "0". In temp3.txt there is word:"only pw3 can work" and "id". So I don't why. And I'm a beginner so I don't know how to debug well.

Comment: It's the first time that I use this webside. I'm not sure that I have notified you by @. Forgive me if you have already get the notify. @kapex

Comment: No problem, welcome to Stackoverflow :) I got the notification but only saw the first sentence, not the update of the comment. So it's good you send one again. Can you try to change all the "temp" file names to something different and run it again? If you do this and the new files are created with the same content as before, then you can at least be sure that everything compiles correctly.

Comment: :), Ok, I have change the all the filenames like this, "temp1.txt" to "temp_1.txt". And only put the three .java file in one folder. I use `cmd` to compile `MyTag.java` and `MyProcessor.java` firstly. Then I use cmd to compile `MyClass.java` with `"-processor MyProcessor"`. The file like "temp_1.txt" created well, and the content in it is still like it in "temp1.txt" (as I mentioned before). There is no warnning in the cmd (at least I can't see). So I think maybe the compile process worked well. @kapex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotation processing can be done in multiple rounds, which means a processor may be called multiple times, with different input. [Here is a nice short explanation of this concept.](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101#processing-rounds)

In your case the processor seems to be called two times. Unfortunately, because `PrintWriter` overwrites old files, the output in `temp1.txt` is only from the second round. The output of the first round looks correct:

```
pw1 can work here
2
pw1 can't work here
pw1 can't work here
```

The second round does not processes any elements with your annotation, so the set is empty. And because this time the loops don't get executed, `temp2.txt` and `temp3.txt` don't get overwritten and still show the output from the first round. To better understand what is happening, you can add a counter to your processor, and add the counter to the file names, e.g. like this:

```
private int round = 0;

@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    round++;

    //...
    pw1 = new PrintWriter(new File("temp1-" + round + ".txt"));
    //...
}
```

By the way, if you want to output messages to see what is happening, you can use the `Messager` that is provided by the processing environment to print errors or notes to the console.

```
processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Kind.NOTE, "MyProcessor, processing round: " + round);
```

Comment: Thank you! What you say is really helpful!